# Why do you say "friend of mine" instead of "friend of me"?

Tags: grammar, double-possessive

I think *friend of mine* can be translated to *my friend.*
In that case, doesn't *friend of me* make more sense?

If we translate *friend of mine* to *one of my friends* then I guess *friend of mine* makes sense for *my friends* being *mine.*

Is there a difference?

When do you say *... of mine* instead of *my ...*?

Is there a specific situation when you use one or the other?

Comment: I believe I have answered the question in detail [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/371652/200388).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When and why we use double-genitive with respect to the word 'of'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/354165/when-and-why-we-use-double-genitive-with-respect-to-the-word-of) The article by Swan (mahmud k pukayoor) is authoritative, comprehensive.

Answer (score 10):

In *friend of mine*, *mine* means *my friends*, so literally *He is [one] friend of [all my friends].* or, more idiomatically, *He is one of my friends.*

If I only have one friend and he is my only friend, we cannot then say "he is a friend of mine", because the "mine" doesn't mean a group of people. If I introduce my daughter I would never say *This is a daughter of mine.* but *This is my daughter.*

Comment: No, I think this is wrong too. "of mine" doesn't mean the person is one of a group. "My" and "mine" are the same words in different cases. "My" is the nominative form.

Comment: The problem here is the article. So, for instance, you can say "This daughter of mine..." and it sounds fine whether she is your only daughter or not.

Comment: @Alan: yes, my answer is wrong too!

Comment: *my* is not nominative.  And *my* and *mine* do not take different cases.

Comment: +1 This answer is (almost) correct. "Mine" is simply the possessive case and thus refers to what the subject owns - perhaps in general, rather than just the collection of his/her friends.

Comment: So it's just a different way of saying the same thing? At least for the case of a friend? "One of my friends" and "a friend of mine" both mean the same? I guess it's just one's preference then. It's shorter and easier to say "a friend of mine."

Comment: @Noldorin: _Mine_ in _a friend of mine_ doesn't refer to what the subject owns.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Actually, it does. Not "owns" in a literal sense, but nonetheless.

Comment: @Noldorin: To me _my friend_ doesn't mean I own my friend; the same is true for _a friend of mine_. _My friend_ (as NOAD reports) means _associated with me_; it's quite different from _to own_.

Answer (score 7):

*Mine* is used to refer a thing belonging to (or a person associated with) the speaker.

Since it is about a friend (who is associated) mine must be used instead of me.

Adapted from [NOAD](http://oxforddictionaries.com/search?searchType=dictionary&isWritersAndEditors=true&searchUri=All&q=mine&_searchBtn=Search&contentVersion=WORLD)

Another usage:

- The picture is mine = It is my picture. (possessive pronoun)
- The picture is me = I am in the picture. (object pronoun)

Comment: "the picture is me" wouldn't that indicate some mental illness on your part, making you think that you are in fact the picture. I mean should that not be "the picture is **of** me"?

Comment: @Johan:  XD practically you're unlikely to be a picture, but philosophically I find this hilarious too.  Reminds me of '[you too could own a photograph](https://dilbert.com/strip/1995-04-19)'.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a specific situation when you use one or the other?

"Friend of mine" would generally be used when you're saying something like "Kim is a friend of mine," in other words, at the end of a phrase or sentence. "My friend" is often used when saying "Kim is my friend", or in the construction, "My friend, you have a rip in the back of your shirt."

Comment: @Shinto Sherlock -- Yes, it does answer the question. The question includes "Is there a specific situation when you use one or the other?" Please explain how providing examples (which I did) does not fulfill that aspect of the question.

Comment: You can say _A friend of mine, Alberto Paderno, lives in Italy._

Answer (score 2):

Ok, sorry, long two-part idea.

1. "of someone" in this case is not really about possession.  My impression is that English speakers do not like to use "of" simply to show possession; we have other grammatical constructions for that.  Instead, "of" is used to refer to patterns of association or constituency in some larger whole, as in "out of" "consisting of".
2. "a friend of mine" is really a shortened form of "a friend of mine (friends)" as argued by other comments.  This means, literally, "one friend out of my several friends".  The OED etymology sections have a long but clear explanation of the history of "mine" and "my" that more or less clears this up.  Historically, "my" originates from a singular version (min) and "mine" from a plural version (mine) which were otherwise grammatically the same.  Therefore, "mine" probably does have something to do with the plurality of friends in this case.  Just like "mine eyes" probably made sense in the the past, but not "mine nose".  One thing that either clinches or messes up this interpretation is that people say "of hers". OED calls this a "double possessive" which developed by extrapolation from 's.  But some dialectical variants use "of hern" instead, which was definitely plural in the past.  Therefore. "hern friends" was used in the past.  Was "hers friends" ever grammatical?  I'm inclined to think this is (historically) about plurality and not about double possession.   Maybe phrases like "of John's" were originally in the plural possessive sense "of Johns" where John has many of something, not where there are many Johns, but were reanalyzed as a new special kind of possessive when this kind of plural possessive was lost.  Therefore, the idea of double possession is a later way of explaining why people speak like this.

Comment: According to this theory, when we say "a friend of his/hers/theirs/ours/mine/John's", the "his/hers/theirs/ours/mine/John's" refer to possession of multiple things? Is that right? And has English ever had a system where genitives/possessives were marked by the number of things being possessed, rather than the number of the "possessor"?

Comment: Ok, you're right....  I guess it's not about plurality.  But, I still think that "of mine" does not have the same meaning in English as "de mi" in Spanish (just as the example I know about), which is part of why "of me" is not used in the same sense.  "of me" can only mean "from me" or "out of me" etc.  So, maybe "of mine" is just a special form of "double" possession as we are told.

Comment: So, for non-English speakers, the thing to take from this is not to use "of" just to show possession.  Say "my friend" instead.  "Friend of mine" might mean the same thing (or might not), but why take the trouble.

Comment: Obviously, I can't stop thinking about this.  Maybe, "friend of mine" differs from "my friend" mainly in terms of definiteness.  Instead of meaning "one of my friends" which would be about number, it means an unspecified friend, of which there might only be one.  That might explain why you can say "This wife of mine...." and it sounds funny but does not necessarily imply that you have multiple wives.  It's funny because you are intentionally not marking her as a specific person, which is denigrating. If you said "my wife" it would not be funny anymore.

Comment: wife of mine = "a wife that I have"

Comment: my wife = "the wife that I have"  ... Doesn't this basically explain the difference.

Comment: This also clarifies why it is easy to see an implication of plurality in the construction.

Answer (score 0):

"Mine" was once used to mean "my." ("Mine eyes have seen the glory...") I would guess that this idiom is a holdover of that usage, although here it functions as an object rather than an adjective.

Comment: -1. This is wrong, consider e.g. "this is mine" rather than "this is my".

Comment: I'm saying it's a shorter linguistic distance from "mine enemy" to "enemy of mine" than to "enemy of me."

Comment: "Mine" was used instead of "my" only before words starting with vowels, AFAIK. ("mine eyes" but not "mine mouth")

Answer (score 0):

Why "of mine" rather than "of me"?

Evidently, it has to do with the function of the preposition "of" in standard modern English.

"That was kind of you to say." Here "of" creates a relationship between "you" and "kind", but does not indicate possession. It simply answers the question: "of whom?".

On the other hand: "Those were kind words of yours." Here, "of" indicates possession, inasmuch as it answers the question: "whose?"

There are certainly English dialect forms that conflate "of whom" and "whose", perhaps in the same way that informal modern German frequently uses the dative instead of the genitive case.

Do you mind me/my closing the window? This illustrates a case in point where standard modern English acknowledges the similarity of both forms.

Comment: and why "of mine" rather than "of mine's"?

Answer (score -1):

The nominative form of "me" is "I". You wouldn't say, for instance,

"He is a colleague of me."

Any more than you would say

"He is I colleague."

You would say:

"He is a colleague of mine"

and

"He is my colleague"

The same goes for friends. For whatever reason, friends, colleagues, etc., are treated as possessions in English.

As noted above, when it's third person, you can do this. But consider:

"A friend of Jane."

and

"Jane friend."

Again, it doesn't work.

Perhaps this use of the non-genitive is just a matter of usage. I'm not sure.

Comment: -1. This is wrong. The question is about contrasting "She is a friend of me" and "She is a friend of mine". "She is a friend of my" wasn't mentioned.

Comment: It's still wrong even with the later assertion in your comment. "Mine" here is not simply what is used when in a prepositional phrase. "Pieces of me" for example would be correct English.

Comment: I don't think I originally said that there is one form for all prepositional phrases, or even the same homophonic preposition. If I did say that, I was wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, though.

Answer (score -2):

*X of me* is always ungrammatical, and I don't think there are any English constructions that use *of me*. The emphatic possessive construction is formed by *of mine*, and the equivalent using other persons (*of yours*, *of hers*, *of Jane's*, *of the cat's*, etc.)

There isn't a logical rule that explains why this is, and there doesn't need to be. That's just how the language works.

Comment: Well, if it always had to be "of yours", "of Jane's", "of mine", etc., then we would say that the syntactic rule is that the "of" used for possession licenses genitive case.  The problem is that you can also say "of Jane", "of the cat", which means that, for some reason, some forms don't *have* to get genitive case.  It seems to just be some of the pronouns where it is required, "of mine" being one of those.

Comment: You'll never see any more of me!

Comment: That's not genitive case...

Comment: It sure as heck is genitive case.  It's actually a matter of whether it is double genitive or not: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genitive_case#Double_genitive

Comment: For the life of me, why didn't I find this forum sooner?

Comment: ♫ All of me, why not take all of me? ♫