# Is " A friend of his dad " a correct sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

A whole sentence is

> He remembered that a friend of his dad's regretted not doing what he wanted to.

Which is from my textbook.

I am wondering if changing "a friend of his dad's" to "a friend of his dad" causes a grammatical error.

Comment: A _grammatical_ error. See [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1535/why-do-you-say-friend-of-mine-instead-of-friend-of-me).